# How to cancel cell editing in Angular ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have some condition in beginCellEdit event

```
       gridApi.edit.on.beginCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, event) {
            var scope = angular.element(event.currentTarget).scope();
            var selectedRowIndex = scope.rowRenderIndex;
            var selectedColumnName = scope.col.name;

            if ($scope.gridOptions.data[selectedRowIndex-1][selectedColumnName].trim()=='') {      
                alert("You cannot enter the value in this cell");
                // At this place I want to cancel edit and return focus to grid
            } 
        })
```

Is there any preventDefault or similar method so can easily cancel the cell editing and return focus to grid.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XHd9vCpTvAHUtxpJRfnR?p=preview) example to have conditional editable field.

**Controller:**

```
var cellEditable = function($scope){
  if($scope.row.entity.oldId4===undefined)
    return false;
  return $scope.row.entity.oldId4!=$scope.row.entity.id4;
}
```

**Gridoptions -> columnDefs:**

```
cellEditableCondition : cellEditable
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to it is to broadcast the IUiGridEditContants.events.END_CELL_EDIT event like so:

```
scope.$broadcast("uiGridEventEndCellEdit");
```

The only drawback is that it will close all of the cells that are in edit mode.

FYI:  The following DID NOT WORK for me:

```
 gridApi.rowEdit.setRowsClean([gridRow.entity]);
```

Comment: Be sure to broadcast either string literal "uiGridEventEndCellEdit" as @CAK2 shows. Or value of variable `uiGridEditConstants.events.END_CELL_EDIT` . Note that `uiGridEditConstants` is an angular constant declared within "ui grid edit module" and needs to be injected into your controller (the way you inject services). Also DO NOT CONFUSE  `uiGridConstants` and `uiGridEditConstants`!